# Is it possible to use ASP.NET Identity information in WordPress (i.e. merge the credential information)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wordpress, asp.net-identity, wordpress-login

I am working on an e-commerce website, which is developed in ASP.NET MVC and uses the ASP.NET Identity for user management. The website users are stored in `user` table.

I have also created a blog for my website using WordPress, the blog can be reached using this subdomain: `blog.my-domain.com`

Now is there any way that I could use the same Identity information (ASP.NET stores User info in Cookies) in my WordPress blog?

This is why I want to combine the Identity information:

Imagine a user is logged in to my website... then he would visit my blog and decides to leave a comment... but he is not logged in the WP, so he would leave a comment as new user.

Comment: Hi @Hooman Bahreini, did you find out how to do it? Struggling with the same problem.

Comment: @Carlos: I didn't, just gave up on the idea!